# Are questions about ways to create libraries for a language on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, asking-questions

I would like to ask a question about possible ways to go about creating a library for a programming language.

> What are some ways to create a library for a programming language?

Would such a question be on-topic here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are some ways to create a library for a programming language?

This is impossibly broad (multiple ways), so it won't be a good question.

There has been a previous meta question [Are library design questions on-topic?](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/37/133), the overwhelmingly top-scored answer to which says **standard library design questions are on-topic, and other libraries are not**. Some other answers propose limited extensions encompassing libraries as domain-specific languages and borderline language features.

Questions about **designing module systems of a language would be on-topic**, as would ones about features for code reuse or namespacing. There have been some of these already that you can find on the site; some of those may also have been a little too broad, but they may answer the question you have already anyway if it's on this sort of topic.

Questions about **generally implementing a library are off-topic**. Questions about **using library systems of an existing language will generally be off-topic** as well. These will be suitable for Stack Overflow.

It's not clear which (if any) of those areas your question is meant to be in, which is another issue that would lead to closure. A good question will be more defined and relate to a concrete design or implementation choice in some context.

Comment: I would add questions about how to define rules for what goes into different libraries, how to organise and verison them are also on topic.